# How to drop HTTP requests in a Java Play! filter?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a filter (coded in Java) that processes every HTTP request made to my app. I want this filter to look at the value of a specific header, and based on that value, drop (i.e. eventually return a 404 error) this current HTTP request.

Is it possible to do this in Play?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly straight-forward.  First of all, read and understand the section on filters in the [documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters).

The implementation of your filter then looks like this:

```
import akka.stream.Materializer;
import play.mvc.Filter;
import play.mvc.Http;

public class HeaderFilter extends Filter {
    @Inject
    public HeaderFilter(final Materializer mat) {
        super(mat);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> apply(final Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> next,
                                         final Http.RequestHeader requestHeader) {
        final String header = requestHeader.getHeader("header name");
        if (some test) {
            // allow the request to continue
            return next.apply(requestHeader);
        } else {
            // block the request
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Results.notFound());
        }
    }
}
```